# Using gulp-modernizr how do I specify feature options

Tags: javascript, gulp, modernizr

My [custom Moderniser build](http://modernizr.com/download/?-backdropfilter-backgroundsize-bgpositionxy-bgrepeatspace_bgrepeatround-bgsizecover-borderradius-cssanimations-cssfilters-csspointerevents-csspseudoanimations-csspseudotransitions-cssremunit-csstransforms-csstransitions-customevent-devicemotion_deviceorientation-eventlistener-flexbox-fontface-json-nthchild-opacity-overflowscrolling-rgba-svg-svgasimg-svgfilters-touchevents-xhrresponsetypejson-domprefixes-setclasses-shiv) includes the following options which I am trying to inject into the [gulp-modernizr](https://github.com/doctyper/gulp-modernizr) tool as follows:

```
gulp.task('modernizr', function() {
  allUISrcPlusSassSrc
    .pipe(modernizr({
      options: [
        'backdropfilter',
        'backgroundsize',
        'bgpositionxy',
        'bgrepeatspace_bgrepeatround',
        'bgsizecover',
        'borderradius',
        'cssanimations',
        'cssfilters',
        'csspointerevents',
        'csspseudoanimations',
        'csspseudotransitions',
        'cssremunit',
        'csstransforms',
        'csstransitions',
        'customevent',
        'devicemotion_deviceorientation',
        'eventlistener',
        'flexbox',
        'fontface',
        'json',
        'nthchild',
        'opacity',
        'overflowscrolling',
        'rgba',
        'svg',
        'svgasimg',
        'svgfilters',
        'touchevents',
        'xhrresponsetypejson',
        'domprefixes',
        'setclasses',
        'shiv'
      ]
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest("./output/js/vendor/"))
});
```

But running this leads to `Building your customized Modernizr{ [Error: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/davesag/src/test-project/node_modules/modernizr/lib/../src/backgroundsize.js'`

Looking in `./node_modules/modernizr/src` I can't see any files that match these options.  Am I just misunderstanding something?  These feature names came straight from my [custom-built modernizr file as downloaded previously from the moderniser website](http://modernizr.com/download/?-backdropfilter-backgroundsize-bgpositionxy-bgrepeatspace_bgrepeatround-bgsizecover-borderradius-cssanimations-cssfilters-csspointerevents-csspseudoanimations-csspseudotransitions-cssremunit-csstransforms-csstransitions-customevent-devicemotion_deviceorientation-eventlistener-flexbox-fontface-json-nthchild-opacity-overflowscrolling-rgba-svg-svgasimg-svgfilters-touchevents-xhrresponsetypejson-domprefixes-setclasses-shiv) includes the following options which I am trying to inject into the [gulp-modernizr](https://github.com/doctyper/gulp-modernizr).

Leaving out the options it builds okay but without the options I'm not getting any feature-classes injected into the HTML element of my page. The supposed auto-detect stuff does not seem to be working.

I checked the [Customizr page as per the docs](https://github.com/doctyper/customizr#config-file) and it seems what I am doing is right. But clearly that's not the case.

How should I be doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`options` refers to the options that are on the left hand side of the Modernizr builder page. These are typically APIs and convenience functions like `Modernizr.mq`, `Modernizr.atRule`, etc.

You want to use the `tests` option

Comment: Cool that builds without errors but it's still not injecting the class names into the `html` tag as before. I guess I need to make some of those into options and the rest as tests.  Will experiment.

Comment: it doesn't by default. you need to add options: ["setclasses"]

Answer (score 0):

@Patrick "it doesn't by default. you need to add options: ["setclasses"]"

Actually it's options: ["set**C**lasses"]